# How to continue running my testcases in the same window using selenium C#?

Tags: selenium

Please help me with this.
My second method is dependent on first method and so on.
I am not using driver.quit() or driver.close()

```
 [TestMethod]
        public void CheckInAsDcs()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Assert.AreEqual(driver.Title, "NeuTravel");
            var selectDropDown = driver.FindElement(By.Id("viewSelect"));
            var dcsOption = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("option"))[1];
            //checking for dcs in dropdown
            var checkForDcs = driver.FindElement(By.Id("viewSelect"));
            dcsOption.Click();
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
}

        [TestMethod]
        public void CreateNewRequest()
        {

            //calling CheckInAsDcs function
             CheckInAsDcs();

            //waiting for the web elements to load
            Thread.Sleep(10000);

            //finding CreateNewRequest button and clicking it
            var selectCreateNewReq = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("input"));
            selectCreateNewReq[0].Click();
}
```